# Save PointCloud2 data

Tags: ros, rosbag, pcl, hokuyo, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running Hokuyo UTM-30LX in real time and getting PointCloud2 published. Each time I move the laser, the previous PointCloud data is lost. How can I save parts of pcl assembled scan?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103881/save-pointcloud2-data/) by [hali19](https://answers.ros.org/users/9076/hali19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have a look at the [laser assembler](http://wiki.ros.org/laser_assembler) package. That one will allow you to create aggregated pointclouds from multiple laser scans and retrieve them via a service. By calling this service from your own node, you could collect pointcloud data over time, save it to .pcd files or do anything else you want.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-11-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hali19](https://answers.ros.org/users/9076/hali19/) on 2013-11-21**:
Thank you, I am learning about using .pcd files